# Is there a way to use os.walk function to go through a user's files from a website built on django?

Tags: python, django, os.walk

I want to do something like this, just that the user will have to browse to the desired folder.

```
rootdir = "/browsed/folder"
    # Iterate the root directory recursively using os.walk
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            fname = os.path.join(root, file)
```

Comment: Can you give some more information please.

Comment: Basically can I walk through folders of any user who visits my website written on django like I do through mine using a python script?

Comment: If you are talking about files on a users local machine then no.